# NSNotificationDefault Center called multiple times even removing observer before adding

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I am adding observer to init method.And for the reason it will not call multiple times I am removing observer before adding it.Even then is is calling as many times as we load the View.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(updateStuff)
                                                     name:@"appDidBecomeActive"
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(closeConnection)
                                                     name:@"appDidEnterBackground"
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(orientationChanges:)
                                                     name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"
                                                   object:nil];

        t=[[Theme alloc] init];
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have also tried it removing in updateStuff method

```
-(void)updateStuff
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Market Watch update stuff called $$$$$$$----------------------");
    [self initNetworkCommunication];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

also tried removing here.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"appDidBecomeActive" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"appDidEnterBackground" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}
```

also tried removing in viewWillDisappear It works fine but here adding observer to viewWillAppear not working.

When I lock the screen and unlock it this observer should call.As it is notified on appDidBecomeActive , and it is working like that. But when I pop back to previous viewController and push to current one and repeats the process of lock and unlock this observer fires two times.As number of times I pop view and push again to current View.Notifier fires number of times I pushed to the View.I know it is because of init method.Whenever view will load it adds an observer but doesn't removes observer.

What can I do other than that.

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; is WRONG. It removes VC from observing system notifications like memory warning notification. You should only call it in dealloc method.

Comment: I have code removing in dealloc method with observer name, that was not working properly so I put removing observer before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to -awakeFromNib instead
Also, try removing the notification in a different manner. I don't have the code but you have to also give it the name of the notification, and you should only remove observer in dealloc

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"appDidBecomeActive" object:nil];  like this ? I have also tried it

Comment: Yup... Thats the one. Then change the location of the calls

Comment: how can I declare awakeFromNib with return type void or id

Comment: added and where to remove, I am currently removing it in dealloc method

Comment: For what youa re doing you dont need to implement init. Most the time init is for objects, awakefromnib for vcs...

Comment: Yea remove ONLY in dealloc. Take out the removes in awakefromnib

Comment: after lock and unlock device it should call

Comment: Ok... I use these all the time and they are added in awakeFromNib. Make sure they are actually being posted

Comment: Then awakeFromNib may not be appropriate. Experiment with different loading stages. Try viewDidLoad?

Comment: FWIW `awakeFromNib` is a UIView method, _not_ a UIViewController method. Sure you can define it in your case, but don't expect it to ever be called by anyone but yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove observer in viewWillDisappear method.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

and remove from initWithNibName.

Comment: viewWillDisappear removes successfully but adding to viewWillAppear not working